# Python: How to use value_counts() inside .agg function in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by, aggregate-functions

Input dataframe `df` looks like:

```
item    row
Apple   12
Apple   12
Apple   13
Orange  13
Orange  14
Lemon   14
```

Output dataframe need to be

```
item    unique_row      nunique_row     count
Apple   {12,13}             2            {2,1}
Orange  {13,14}             2            {1,1}
Lemon   {14}                1            {1}
```

**Tried Code:**

```
df.groupby('item', as_index=False)['row'].agg({'unique_row': lambda x: set(x)
                                                ,'nunique_row': lambda x: len(set(x))})
```

So here, not sure how to add condition inside `.agg` function to generate column '`count`'. Column '`count`' represents number of `value_count` for each row value.
Any help will be appreciated. Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert to list or set:

```
(df.groupby('item', as_index=False)['row']
   .agg({'unique_row': lambda x: list(x.unique()),
         'nunique_row': lambda x: len(set(x)),
         'count': lambda x: list(x.value_counts(sort=False)), # or set(x.value_counts())
        })
)
```

output:

```
     item unique_row  nunique_row   count
0   Apple   [12, 13]            2  [2, 1]
1   Lemon       [14]            1     [1]
2  Orange   [13, 14]            2  [1, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution

```
s = df.value_counts()
g = s.reset_index(name='count').groupby('item')

g.agg(list).join(g.size().rename('nunique_row'))
```

#### Working

- Calculate the groupsize per `item` and `row` using `value_counts`
- group the preceding counts by `item`

  - `agg` with `list` to get the list of unique rows and corresponding counts
  - `agg` with `size` to get number of unique rows

##### Result

```
             row   count  nunique_row
item                                 
Apple   [12, 13]  [2, 1]            2
Lemon       [14]     [1]            1
Orange  [13, 14]  [1, 1]            2
```